# handling data violation in c

Tags: c, windows

I am starting to learn c and cannot find a clear example of handling memory violations.  Currently I have written a piece of code that uses a variable and an array.

I assign a value to the variable and then populate the array with a set of initial values.  However one of the values in the array is being saved at the same address as the variable and hence overwriting the variable.

Could some one please give me a simple example of how to handle such errors or to avoid such errors....thanks

Answer (score 3):

Once an error such as a memory violation has occurred in C, you cannot 'handle' it. So, you have to avoid it in the first place. The way to do what you want is as follows:

```
int a[10];
int i;
for( i = 0;  i < 10;  i++ )
    a[i] = 5;
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the memory violation in the first place.  I mean would it be possible to check when defining the array that each address in the array is free and not being used already.  And if so how would i do that....Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "check when defining the array that each address in the array is free and not being used already". When you say `int a[10]` you are given a perfectly valid array in which all 10 elements are guaranteed to be there and available for you to use. But no more than 10.

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess but seems pretty much your problem.
You are overwriting beyond the bounds of the array.

C does not guard you against writing beyond the bounds of an allocated array. You as a programmer must ensure you do not do so. Failing to do so will result in **Undefined Behavior** and then anything can happen(literally) your program might work or might not or show unusual behavior.

For eg:

```
int arr[10];
```

Declares an array of `10` integers and the valid subscript range is from `0` to `9`,
You should ensure your program uses valid subscripts.